# Azure Data Studio - Trying to connect Postgres DB from remote

Tags: azure-devops

I downloaded 'PostgresSQL extension'. While I am choosing Postgres in connection type, I am getting an error. Please help to resolve this.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by installing via Github. Some have Postgresql tools not properly loaded while I am loading for Azure Data studio.